# Restcomm login page error: webpage not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobicents, amazon-marketplace, restcomm

I followed instruction in a [restcomm video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsUp7PyMzc0) to access restcomm via AWS marketplace (I chose the recommended 'large' instance).  I had no issue performing all of the steps mentioned.

However, when I try to access restcomm login page, I get a "webpage not available" error.

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: here is [Amazon Aws URL](http://ec2-52-6-240-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/restcomm-management/) i'm redirected to that throws error.

EDIT: [Screen Shot is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RUFk.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: You may want to provide a link to restcomm as most people are not likely to be familiar with it.  More importantly though, you need to provide an example of your code so that others can help you understand what you did that differs from the correct way.

Comment: Appreciate your assistance to help me post question properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing Restcomm from your Amazon Cloud instance, please note that you need to use the correct URL

http://IP_OF_RESTCOMM_AMAZOM_INSTANCE:8080

Please see the getting started page of Restcomm for login details.

http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-quick-start-guide/

Comment: IP of RestComm amazon instance looks all right. 
Here is Url 
http://ec2-52-4-128-225.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/restcomm-management/ 
But i'm getting same error "This webpage is not available". 
Is there anything else am i missing here ?
Thanks.

Comment: It should be http://IP_OF_RESTCOMM_AMAZOM_INSTANCE:8080 not http://IP_OF_RESTCOMM_AMAZOM_INSTANCE:8080/restcomm-management. This has changed with new RestComm release

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your amazon instance is up and running and that you are using the correct domain/IP to access Restcomm. I pinged both ec2-52-6-240-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com and ec2-52-4-128-225.compute-1.amazonaws.com and none of them seems to respond.

Comment: The instance doesn't seem to be running.  You might want to try rebooting the instance and try to access the /restcomm-management page again.

Comment: i terminate the instance once i'm done with it. You may ping me at  abdr.y at outlook dot com. i will start instance when you are online for you to giev it a go. Thanks TechBoy